# Use same toolbar in all ViewControllers

Tags: swift, ios8, navigation, toolbar

I've created a `UIToolbar` like a menu in my app in the top, but I need to use it in all the ViewControllers that I have in my app, just like reuse it when I navigate in the app to the next screens.

How I can achieve this ?

Comment: Same question. Still actual.

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev I solved the problem, in a few days I'll update the answer